# poll() system call stuck in restart_syscall()

Tags: linux, system-calls, systems-programming

Intermittently process is getting stuck in poll call. This process reads the data received on a socket using poll system call. After restart it runs fine for some days and then does not read anything from socket.

tcpdump shows the data is received on the port as expected. But, not read by the process.

strace output is as below,

```
VMFR2 tmp# strace -p 16528
Process 16528 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>
```

Please share pointer on how can I debug/resolve the issue?

Comment: I'd try to attach with a debugger and check the `poll()` arguments.

Comment: ... or to attach `strace` before the process gets stuck.